# How many possible combinations when interactions are allowed?

Tags: statistics, combinations

Is there an easy way to determine how many possible combinations are available when I have six parameters but I allow all to interact as pairs?

The background for this question comes from statistics. I am conducting regression modelling and I have six predictor variables.

Let´s say I have the predictors called X1,X2,X3,X4,X5, and X6.

Then, I could calculate of all possible "additive" combinations representing one single regression like Y ~ X1  or Y ~ X1 + X2 with 2^6 / 2, which would be 32. So given 6 parameters there would be 32 unique combinations of how I could create my regression formula. This is used for example in so called all-subset regression approaches.

Now, let´s say I want to allow that multiplications between predictors, i.e. X1*X2 and X1*X3 and so forth should be considered, too. Of course, combined with the additive parts. How many combinations would that be? How could I easily determine this number using simple calculus for example something lke (2^6)^2 (which is wrong)?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please elaborate

Comment: thank you, I have hopefully added enough context now? Sorry, for being unclear.